# Does ringing a bell show the stronghold in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

I've been wondering this for a while. I heard that if you ring a bell, it'll show particles around it if there is a stronghold nearby. If that's true, does it do it on the PS4?

Answer (score 2):

In Bedrock a Stronghold often spawns under a village, but ringing the bell doesn't do anything related to its presence.

The only way to know if there's a Stronghold below is throwing an Eye of Ender.
Or dig straight down. (Please, don't do it.)

Comment: Do it, do it, doooo iiiiit! :D Digging straight down isn't that dangerous, you'll be fiiiiiine.... as long as you are standing between two blocks and dig a 2x1